# Home button disable by keyguard

Tags: android

I know that a lot of people ask about this issue
and i also know that at older version we could ovveride the home button 
and today in ics and jelly it is not possible any more.
i know also that key guard can remove my lockscreen.

**But can some one for the first time in the history of stackoverflow help in that isuue?**

How can i make a screen stuck with out the ability to close it with the home button?(kind of lock screen)
(Like the app: Picture Password Lockscreen) (found in google play)

Answer (score -1):

You have to know how to lock all buttons (as they do in the Picture Password Lockscreen)?

Comment: this is comment not answer.